# Executing Sonar Runner with Delphi failed

Tags: delphi, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Here's the `sonar-runner.properties` file in the project's root directory.

```
sonar.projectKey=baedalpos
sonar.projectName=baedal
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.scm.provider=svn
sonar.language=delph
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=false
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=/home/svntest/30.1.Client/.
```

As you can see above, the project is written in Delphi, so I already downloaded and installed the Delphi plugin. When I run the `sonar-runner` command, it ends up leaving the following error message.

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 10.024s
Final Memory: 55M/807M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 737 is not a valid line for pointer. File [moduleKey=baedalpos, relative=Basic/uStoreTable.pas, basedir=/home/svntest/30.1.Client TEST] has 525 line(s)
        at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:215)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:209)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.selectLine(DefaultInputFile.java:246)
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.DeprecatedIssueBuilderWrapper.line(DeprecatedIssueBuilderWrapper.java:59)
        at org.sonar.plugins.delphi.metrics.DeadCodeMetrics.save(DeadCodeMetrics.java:168)
        at org.sonar.plugins.delphi.DelphiSensor.processFiles(DelphiSensor.java:134)
        at org.sonar.plugins.delphi.DelphiSensor.analyse(DelphiSensor.java:112)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: The plugin might be just outdated. From where did you get it? I'm a bit sceptical to that someone maintained it for free until the recent Delphi versions.

Comment: I don't think the plugin itself is outdated. Here's where I found the Delphi plugin: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi . According to this page, the latest version was 0.3.3, (https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/releases/tag/0.3.3), and I downloaded and installed following the direction exactly

Comment: Probably there's something missing in the configuration part.. still working on it..

Comment: More than 1 year is enough to change the plugin interface :) Maybe try to install SonarQube Runner version from that time.

Comment: That's what I believe as well, but there has been no update for the last 2 years, according to the page.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's why the link [SonarQube Runner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner) from that plugin repository links to a non existing page. The plugin is not written in Delphi but is written in Java to analyze Delphi code. This is a question for the plugin author.